# Does zsh support hash table as a built-in data type?

Tags: linux, shell, zsh

If supported, which version of zsh should I use to take advantage of this feature?
How to declare and use it in code?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Zsh supports hash tables, a quick google search returns many results.

You must first typeset the variable:

```
% typeset -A hash
```

then you can store items in the table:

```
% hash[brown]="mm..  hash browns"
% hash[table]="clever data structure"
```

then you recover them as usual with arrays:

```
% print ${hash[brown]}
```

Comment: Just a remark: This kind of variables are called _associative arrays_ in `zsh`.

Comment: So they are in PHP, also; it's the rest of the world that calls them _hash tables_.

Comment: in PHP they are hash tables but, associative arrays don't have to be hash tables:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134296/hash-tables-vs-associative-arrays

Comment: Technically, "associative array" is one name for the abstract data type (sometimes more simply called a "map"); a "hash table" is just one particular implementation of that type, albeit probably the most popular one.  Languages like Perl and Ruby call their associative structures "hashes" because it's pithier than "associative arrays" and avoids any confusion with "map" the higher-order function.